# :::rolls down window::: pardon me, can you help me find

Tags: discussion, new-users, profile-page

I hate to post this here, since it's not about MV's, but the very helpful Paulster2 said there were helpful people here and such and I honestly have looked in dozens of other places for an answer ....
How do I change my user name?? (&/or image) I've looked all over the ios app and the desktop sites and can't find anything to let me do that. I can't find a "SE Community", or even a "how to" use the site, or a Meta for profiles, or an understandable, simple contact / feedback form. SE is seemingly unique, with "membership" to the individual sites within, and a different profile for each (kinda like meetup.com?) But, much harder for me to navigate (&, I'm usually pretty good at this stuff!)

If you're not used to people asking questions like this here, then just imagine I'm IN my car and have lost my way...

Thanks, in advance!!

~a somewhat embarassed noob (aka maria)

(Also, sorry for the tag, SE made me pick one and wouldnt let me create "profile" b/c i'm new)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Cheers!

Comment: Welcome from me too! It's really cool that you cared enough to ask you question instead of leaving a place that can be a bit complicated. Though I'm new to this site, I've been on the SE Network for over a year, and still have trouble finding answers to the questions that other people can find so easily. You've definitely found a great community. Everyone here is really nice, and I'm hoping you stay around. Now that you have over 20 rep, feel free to go to the [chat] room. People in there love to answer questions, not just about the site, but about the system. Have fun!

Comment: @DucatiKiller - many thanks! 

Comment: Sue - thanks for the encouragement!! Yes, it's been very frustrating trying to learn and navigate this site (SE) as a member!! That's with having used it as a non-member several times! And, I consider myself a fairly seasoned web user (have even designed a few sites, myself)! In fact, and I'm being 100% truthful here, had it not been for the nice folks like @Paulster2, rviertel, Bob and others (&, now, you!), I would have totally thrown in the towel!! ~maria

Comment: @Sue thanks for pointing to the chat. That saved me a step. Everyone should feel free to stop by the chat anytime. I'll likely be there talking about almost anything except cars because I'm weird that way....  ;-)

Comment: Hi maria - just a welcome from me too. I'm not anywhere as good a mechanic as the others here, but I take part in a lot of SE sites, so get a reasonable overview. One of the additional things you can use is the meta for **all** SE sites at meta.stackexchange.com - which has answers to many of the questions around how SE works in general, as opposed to meta.mechanics, which is focused on this single site.

Comment: @RoryAlsop - thanks for the clarification and added tip!

Answer (score 11):

Welcome to the site!

Quesitions on how this site works go here in Meta.Mechanics.Stackexhange.com

> I can't find a "SE Community", or even a "how to" use the site

Start by taking [The Tour](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tour)

> How do I change my user name?? (&/or image)

Click on your icon at the top of the page, the area inside the red circle below

[image]

This takes you to your profile. There you will find a lot of information including your Questions, Answers, Reputation etc.

Click on the Edit Profile & Settings

[image]

Then you can change your display name and picture

[image]

Finally the contact us and feedback (just a link to Meta) are at the bottom of every page

[image]

Comment: You're the man, Larry. Thanks for helping @maria out. I hate how little you should actually do in comments, but I did what I could.

Comment: BTW, your illustration annotations leave a little to be desired :o)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 My circles have souls! :) See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138031/132547), and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/132547)

Comment: But all circles have holes .... I don't see the big deal ...  :o)

Comment: I don't fully understand all of this, but the answer was helpful and the comments were pretty funny. Thanks for the smiles, all-around! :)

Comment: @MoveMoreCommentsLinkToTop  Those are very nice red circles in your pictures.  Skillzzz

Answer (score 5):

We're building a Q&A dedicated to help new site users as well:

[Helping our new users make the transition](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1460/helping-our-new-users-make-the-transition)

We'd love it if you could contribute there as well.

Answer (score 3):

Let's also not forget [the FAQ on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) which include answers to many of the questions new users might have. For example: [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users)

This leads me to my next point: the best way to contact individual site users is to use the site chat. On Mechanics we have [The Pitstop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop). Here you'll find many connected users who will be happy to answer your (imho not so) trivial questions. You'll probably need a bit of rep to join.