# I keep on repeating the same answer for different questions

Tags: discussion

Lack of fuel pressure is a prime cause for hot-start problems.

To date, I've repeated this message in [5 different answers](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bhot-start%5D%20user%3A675%20is%3Aanswer).

I'm not sure a canonical answer would work here since every vehicle will have its own unique circumstances. But at the same time I find this recycling of the same information far from streamlined.

What should be done here? A few ideas:

1. ***Create a canonical Q&A for hot-start problems***

   I'm reluctant to do this because I don't want people to think that insufficient fuel pressure is the only possible root cause.
2. ***Let the status quo be***

   But I feel that this is against the spirit of Stack Exchange.
3. ***Link to an existing answer***

   This is what I'm sort of doing right now.

Answer (score 7):

My opinion is that where we can use exactly the same answer for a number of questions we have two options:

- we close as duplicate. This is what we currently do. It works, and fits in with the SE framework, but can end up a wee bit messy if there are lots of questions, or if they don't quite fit.
- create a canonical answer (or update the dupe target) in order to fit all (or most) instances of that question type.

I'd suggest the second option is appropriate where we see a high number of questions with the same general answer. This has worked well on other sites (eg [this question on rolling your own crypto](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/18197/485) on Security Stack Exchange)

Comment: I guess what I (or someone else) could do is post a generic Q&A like "What is a hot-start problem and what could cause it?" and treat this as the quasi-canonical and link it in vehicle-specific answers. That way if additional vehicle-specific information is to be addressed, it can be done in the answer to the vehicle-specific question.

Comment: @Zaid I feel like this sorta opens up a new question.  it would be nice if that one meta https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1460/22368 could be broken out into a bunch of mod approved, super generic questions so that we had a starting point for all the "I have common problem X."  Akin to a sticky'd thread on a differently formatted forum